# How do I remove a "missing" MP3 file from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I have an MP3 file located on my iPhone that I want to delete but am unable to find in the Music app.

The track only appears when I connect my iPhone to my Mac and go to (Devices > iPhone > Music) in iTunes. There, it shows a list of all of my voice memos and songs in my music library. I have already deleted all of the songs from my music library using (Settings > General > Usage > Music...) on my iPhone, but it did not delete the file in question. I know absolutely for certain that it is not a voice memo.

There is now a circle with an exclamation mark next to the file in iTunes, but secondary clicking on it does not offer a remove or delete option. Does anyone have any suggestions on removing the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to successfully remove the listing by downloading the iOS file explorer iFunbox and poking around inside of the iPhone's raw filesystem.

The process I took was rather unscientific, but after deleting many of the files and directories located in directories such as Downloads, MediaAnalysis, and Music and iTunes-related folders, the bad listing disappeared.

My suspicion is that the file was appearing because of a bad SQL entry, and that deleting all of the .sqlite files fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you or have you ever used iTunes to sync the phone?  If so, try another sync.

Comment: Yes, I have synced repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reset iTunes cache?

```
iTunes -> Peferences -> Advanced
```

As an option go to `About this mac -> Storage` click `Manage…` and then select `iTunes`. Perhaps those file will be there.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already tried the other answers, back up your iPhone & then restore it in iTunes - this will almost certainly fix this issue.

Comment: Performing a full backup to the computer then restoring the iPhone to the backup did not solve the issue.

Comment: Hmm. Is the file taking up space on the iPhone? It doesn't seem like it's actually there, which is an issue with iTunes if so